# false command ("dc" instead of "cd") - what did it do?

Tags: command-line

recently I made a mistake by mis-typing a command. I was using the *terminal* which opened up in a certain directory (which was NOT empty BTW).
From there I wanted to go to the parent directory by typing `cd ..`

Yet by mistake I typed `dc ..` The terminal responded with:

```
dc: Will not attempt to process directory ..
```

Does anybody know what I have done? I hope everything´s still alright despite my error as `echo $?` still yielded an exit code of "0" (zero).

Thanks a lot in advance.
Many greetings from Rosika

P.S.:

my system: Linux/Lubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, 64 bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't done anything bad.

If you type `man dc`, you will see the manual pages for the `dc` command.  It's just "an arbitrary precision calculator".

It can accept commands from a file and, since you didn't provide one, it didn't do anything useful.  Indeed, in the future, you can use the `man` command to see if there is a manual for that command.  Also, you can type `which dc`, so that you can find out where this `dc` command actually is.

Most commands (not all) will support `--help` or `-h` as well, to provide you with some information about the command.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. In the meantime I also looked up `man dc`. "dc - an arbitrary precision calculator". The one thing I wasn´t sure about are the two dots which I added as kind of an argument. But it´s all clear now. Thanks a lot for your tips as well. You´ve been of great help. It´s much appreciated. Greetings.

Comment: @Rosika the two dots mean "the parent directory". One dot is "the current directory" and two means the parent. For example `cd ..` will move you to the parent directory. So when you ran `dc ..`, that meant "launch the program `dc` with the parent directory as an argument" and since `dc` cannot do anything with a directory as an argument, it tells you "Will not attempt to process directory DIRNAME", it's just that here, the name of the directory is `..` so that's what you see.

Comment: @Rosika Sorry for not clarifying!  Indeed, you wanted to go to the parent directory by typing `cd ..`.  That's what `..` means -- the parent directory.  So, `cp abc ..` would copy the file `abc` to the parent directory.  Similarly, `dc ..` would apply `dc` to the parent directory.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks a lot. Yes, with `cd ..` I indeed wanted to move to the parent directory. Basically I just mistyped my command. I had never dealt with `dc` before and thus was not sure about what it did. Well, it´s clear now that the parent directory cannot be used as an argument for calculation processes. Thanks a lot for the clarification. Greetings.

Comment: @Ray: Thanks a lot for your help and for providing an example referring to `cp`. Everythings´s clear now. Many greetings.

Comment: @Rosika You're welcome!  I think the one time you should panic is if you execute the wrong command with `sudo`.  You could make a big mistake like remove your entire file system, etc.  i.e. `rm -f -r /home/mine /` instead of `rm -f -r /home/mine/`.  The former would delete your entire file system.  Take a deep breath before executing any `sudo` command...  Then, do regular backups and what you could possibly do to your own files is minimal...

Comment: Hi @Ray. Thanks for this good advice of yours. I´ve made it a habit of mine to perform regular backups making (hopefully) good use of **clonezilla live** (once a month). Still I like to learn more about Linux (distros) and how they work. Hence my question here. Thanks so much for helping. Greetings.